# Bash: For loop with binary range keeping control value binary

Tags: bash, binary, for

Let's say I have two bash variables that contain binary values:

```
a=0011 # decimal 3
b=1000 # decimal 8
```

Is there a way I can loop through all the possible values between `$a` and `$b` keeping it binary? Something like:

```
for blah in $(seq $a $b) ; do
    print "Blah is: $blah"
done
```

So it will output:

```
Blah is: 0011
Blah is: 0100
Blah is: 0101
Blah is: 0110
Blah is: 0111
Blah is: 1000
```

I have tried:

```
for blah in $(seq "$((2#$a))" "$((2#$b))") ; do
```

But then `$blah` becomes decimal, and I'd like to keep it a binary (I can always transform the decimal back to binary, but that seems a waste, since I alredy have the *extremes* in binary)

This code must run in a limited linux ([OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/)) that doesn't have `obase` available. If the answer is that *it's not possible to keep the binary value*, that's a useful answer as well (I can create a function that converts decimal to binary without using `obase`) Besides, it can be a useful answer to people using regular `bash`.

Comment: Do you have the `dc` command?

Comment: @jthill, I'm afraid I don't, either **:-(**

Comment: Do you really have bash? Which version?

Comment: 4.2.28(1)-release (mips-openwrt-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seq` is not a built-in. It's also not part of the Posix standard. But the usual implementations of `seq` don't have any ability to sequence in bases other than 10.

In bash, you can specify a range as `{start..finish}`. However, that also doesn't work in bases other than 10 (although it does work with letters: `{a..f}` expands to `a b c d e f`.

And as far as I know, that's it for simple sequence generators, which leaves you with a couple of possibilities.

The silly way to do it is to filter out the non-binary values. That's simple but hugely inefficient if `a` and `b` aren't tiny:

```
for x in $(seq -w $a $b); do
  if [[ ! ($x =~ [2-9]) ]]; then
    echo $x
  fi
done
```

Here's a better solution. Assuming `a` and `b` are the same length (if not, you can use printf to fix that), the following will loop through all binary numbers from a to b, inclusive:

```
# We need a string of 0s at least as long as a:
z=${a//1/0}
while [[ ! ($a > $b) ]]; do
  # do something with $a
  # The following "increments" a by removing the last 0 (and trailing 1s)
  # and replacing that with a 1 and the same number of 0s.
  a=$(printf "%.*s" ${#a} ${a%0*}1$z)
done
```

Comment: Clever second trick!

Answer (score 4):

You're close with this:

```
for blah in $(seq "$((2#$a))" "$((2#$b))") ; do
```

You just need to convert the decimal values from the `for` loop back into binary with something like `dc`.

#### Example

```
$ for blah in $(seq "$((2#0011))" "$((2#1000))"); do \
     printf "%04d\n" $(echo "obase=2;$blah" | bc);done
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
```

The `printf` is being used to control the output so that it's padded with leading zeros, and formatted to a certain width. The arguments, `%04d` is what specifies the output.

The other key pieced to this command is the use of `bc` - a command line calculator. This command for example:

```
echo "obase=2;$blah" | bc
```

Is taking the value, `$blah` and converting it to base 2 (aka. Binary) through the use of `bc`.

#### Without bc or dc

If you're on a system that's limited such that neither of these tools are present you can do the conversion directly using just `awk` and this function from `awk`'s manual.

- [9.1.6 Bit-Manipulation Functions - GNU awk user's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bitwise-Functions.html)

#### Example

Create a file with the following content, call it `dec2bin.awk`.

```
# bits2str --- turn a byte into readable 1's and 0's

function bits2str(bits, data, mask)
{
    if (bits == 0)
        return "0"

    mask = 1
    for (; bits != 0; bits = rshift(bits, 1))
        data = (and(bits, mask) ? "1" : "0") data

    while ((length(data) % 8) != 0)
        data = "0" data

    return data
}

{
  printf("%s\n", bits2str($1))
}
```

Now to use the above function:

```
$ for blah in $(seq "$((2#0011))" "$((2#1000))"); do echo $blah \
     | awk -f dec2bin.awk; done
00000011
00000100
00000101
00000110
00000111
00001000
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier with `zsh`:

```
for ((i=2#$a; i<=2#$b; i++)) echo $(([##2]i))
```

Or with 0-padding:

```
for ((i=2#$a; i<=2#$b; i++)) printf '%04d\n' $(([##2]i))
```

Otherwise you can use `bc`:

```
echo "ibase=obase=2; for (i=$a; i<=$b; i++) i" | bc
```

Or `dc`:

```
echo "2doi $a [p1+d$b!<a]dsax" | dc
```

To 0-pad, you can always pipe the output to:

```
sed 's/^/000/;s/^0*\(.\{4\}\)/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will do a lot of processing, so not good for large ranges.

`seq -f '%04g' 0011 1000 | grep -v '[2-9]'`

Comment: @Stephane the quotes you added and the ones your removed are both optional, in this case. I would recommend always having them.

Comment: No, the quotes around `[2-9]` are not optional. It will cause it to fail with `csh`, `tcsh` or `zsh` if there's no file matching that pattern in the current directory, or worse with other shells (not fish), it will fail badly and more obscurely if there are files matching that pattern in the current directory. You're right that quotes around `%` are necessary for the `fish` shell. single quotes are better than double quotes as in your earlier version since that means it also works with `rc` and `es`. As it is written now, it would work with any shell (on systems where GNU `seq` is installed).

Comment: @stephane Sorry I missed those cases where it did not work, this is why I recommend using quotes where ever they may be needed.